# JSON Encoding error

Tags: php, json

I am trying to send information JSON encoded as shown below, but three of the parameters are being shown before the opening brackets of the encoding:

```
$res = array(
    'price_basic' => do_shortcode("[woocommerce_price id=" . $product_id_basic . "]"),
    'button_basic' => do_shortcode("[add_to_cart id=" . $product_id_basic . "]"),
    'price_plus' => do_shortcode("[woocommerce_price id=" . $product_id_plus . "]"),
    'button_plus' => do_shortcode("[add_to_cart id=" . $product_id_plus . "]"),
    'price_premium' => do_shortcode("[woocommerce_price id=" . $product_id_premium . "]"),
    'button_premium' => do_shortcode("[add_to_cart id=" . $product_id_premium . "]")
);

echo json_encode($res);
```

The encoding:

```
1415.903179.905615.90{"price_basic":"","button_basic":"\t\t\t\n\t\t<p class=\"product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline \"style=\"text-align: center;\">\n\n\t\t\t<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"https:\/\/azooree.com\/product\/hz1-solo-light-packer
```

Those 3 initial values are 1415.90, 3179.90 and 5615.90 that should be respectively in `price_basic`, `price_plus` and `price_premium`.

Comment: Does `do_shortcode` echo out anything before returning? If so, that'll be your problem.

Comment: but the button ones are in the perfect place..

Comment: but no it does not echo anything @ChrisForrence

Comment: @ChrisForrence one of the shortcodes that were being called did have a echo, I'm sorry. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Always seems to be something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to answer this question:

One of the shortcodes called upon the function did have an echo as return method. I changed it to `return` instead.